# How can I enable function keys on an external keyboard only?

Tags: google-chrome-os

I'm using a Chromebook Pixelbook attached to a standard external keyboard. The top-row keys on the Pixelbook keyboard have special functions, for example, change volume, brightness, etc. This is great on the internal keyboard, but I'd like the function keys on the external keyboard to work as labelled, that is, <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>. How can I achieve this?

Currently, the function keys on the external keyboard have Chrome OS special functions, such as change volume, which confuses me.

Comment: worse even, the F-keys on a "multimedia" keyboard like the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard are not activated even after the simple switch mentioned by Colonel Panic.-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting under *Device* → *Keyboard*, "Treat top-row keys as function keys" which can be toggled on or off.

Unfortunately, it applies to both the internal and external keyboard. See feature request *[Treat top-row keys as function keys for external keyboard only](https://crbug.com/1060704)*.

Comment: The page linked shows me "Permission denied.", was the request trashed or is it to be watched elsewhere?

Comment: @Huge I suspect bug https://crbug.com/1060704 was accidentally made internal to Google.